# Change UI Tab bar Display color

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am new to ios. I want make app in tab bar

The tab bar colors now in this scren shot.

[image]

An the UI i want in my iphone is this image
[image]

IN each of icon of tab bar i used black images

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @DanF U can see tha change in color in Tab Bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the app delegate you will need to add some code like this.

```
//Get the Tab Bar
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBarController.delegate = self;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

//You may want to set the background of the tab bar (optional)
[tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CustomTabBar.png"]];

//You will need to repeat this code for each tab bar item
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
tabBarItem3.title = @"Settings";
tabBarItem3.image = nil;
[tabBarItem3 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-button-selected.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-button.png"]];
```

Don't forget to make @2x images for retina support.

You can also change other settings for each tabBarItem - check out the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW28) to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set each of your `UITabBarItems` separately using something like:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title1" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] tag:1];
[tabBarItem1 setFinishedSelectedImage:nil withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
[[myTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] setTabBarItem:tabBarItem1];
```

for each of your view controllers.